# Following this tutorial but I'm stuck on the asyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am a beginner learning to develop android application, and I am currently following this simple tutorial at http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/, but on one of the page I am having problem with NetworkOnMainThreadException, which after I researched, android 3.0 and above will throw the exception when performing http request on UI thread, and that I have to use AsyncTask. I have been trying to modify the code to perform the request onPostExecute, but I keep getting errors.

Here is the java code :

```
package com.example.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class EditProductActivity extends Activity {

    EditText txtName;
    EditText txtPrice;
    EditText txtDesc;
    EditText txtCreatedAt;
    Button btnSave;
    Button btnDelete;

    String pid;

    //progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    //JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    //single product url
    private static final String url_product_details = "http://api.kerjaapa.com/android_connect/get_product_details.php";

    //url to update product
    private static final String url_update_product = "http://api.kerjaapa.com/android_connect/update_product.php";

    //url to delete product
    private static final String url_delete_product = "http://api.kerjaapa.com/android_connect/delete_product.php";

    //JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCT = "product";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";
    private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_product);

        //save button
        btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

        //getting product details from intent
        Intent i = getIntent();

        //getting product id(pid) from intent
        pid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_PID);

        //getting complete product details in background thread
        new GetProductDetails().execute();

        //save button click event
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //starting background task to update product
                new SaveProductDetails().execute();
            }
        });

        //Delete button click event
        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //deleting product in background thread
                new DeleteProduct().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    //Background Async Task to Get Complete Product Details
    class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        //Before starting background thread show progress dialog
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading product details. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        //getting product details in background thread
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            //updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    //Check for success tag
                    int success;
                    try {
                        //Building Parameters
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                        //getting product details by making HTTP request
                        //Note that product details url will use GET request
                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                                url_product_details, "GET", params);

                        //check your log for json response
                        Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                        //json success tag
                        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                        if (success == 1) {
                            //successfully received product details
                            JSONArray productObj = json
                                .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); //JSON Array

                            //get first product object from JSON Array
                            JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                            //product with this pid found
                            //Edit text
                            txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
                            txtPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
                            txtDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

                            //display product data in editText
                            txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
                            txtPrice.setText(product.getString(TAG_PRICE));
                            txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));

                        } else {
                            //product with pid not found
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

            return null;
        }

        //After completing background task dismiss the progress dialog
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            //dismiss the dialog once got all details
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }

    //Background Async Task to Save product details
    class SaveProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        //Before starting background thread, show dialog
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Saving product ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        //Saving product
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            //getting updated data from EditTexts
            String name = txtName.getText().toString();
            String price = txtPrice.getText().toString();
            String description = txtDesc.getText().toString();

            //Building parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PID, pid));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_NAME, name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PRICE, price));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description));

            //sending modified data through http request
            //Notice that update product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_update_product, 
                "POST", params);

            //check json success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    //successfully updated
                    Intent i = getIntent();
                    //send result code 100 to notify about product update
                    setResult(100, i);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    //failed to update product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        //After completing background task, dismiss dialog
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            //dismiss dialog
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }    
    }

    //Background async task to delete product
    class DeleteProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        //Before starting, show progress dialog
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Deleting Product...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        //Deleting product
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {


            //check for success tag
            int success;
            try {
                //Building parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                //getting product details by making HTTP request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        url_delete_product, "POST", params);

                //check your log for json response
                Log.d("Delete product", json.toString());

                //json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    //product successfully deleted
                    //notify previous activity by sending code 100
                    Intent i = getIntent();
                    //send result code 100 to notify about product deletion
                    setResult(100, i);
                    finish();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        //After completing background task dismiss dialog
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            //dismiss dialog once finish
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is in the GetProductDetails class where it used runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){public void run(), I tried erasing these block and the app would run, but sometimes it works and other times it resulted in RunTimeException, and the app would crash. I also tried to pass the variable success to onPostExecute(), then in onPostExecute(), if success == 1, show the result of the JSON call, but after tweaking the code, I keep getting errors and couldn't fix it. What is the best practice on using asyncTask in projects like this ?

Any guidance is very well appreciated.

Thx in advance

Comment: The entire point of `doInBackground` is that it **doesn't** run on the UI thread

Comment: You need to know that there are two kinds of thread, one runs on UI and the other runs on background. In AsycTask, the one runs in background is doInBackground and in your case you are adding runOnUIThread which runs on UI in it. If you want to update UI before your process completes, then you should use onProgressUpdate

Comment: I know this  but after I removed the runOnUiThread, I still get RuntimeException error,what should I do to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not modify the UI in `doInBackground`.

In this case, I think you should be passing your `product` object to your `onPostExecute`, which runs on the UI thread and where you can modify your UI:

```
//Background Async Task to Get Complete Product Details
class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
    //Before starting background thread show progress dialog
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading product details. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    //getting product details in background thread
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
        //Check for success tag
        int success;
        try {
            //Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));
            //getting product details by making HTTP request
            //Note that product details url will use GET request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    url_product_details, "GET", params);

            //check your log for json response
            Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());
            //json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                //successfully received product details
                JSONArray productObj = json
                        .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); //JSON Array

                //get first product object from JSON Array
                JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                return product;

            } else {
                //product with pid not found
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    //After completing background task dismiss the progress dialog
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject product) {
        //Edit text
        txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
        txtPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
        txtDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

        //display product data in editText
        txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
        txtPrice.setText(product.getString(TAG_PRICE));
        txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));

        //dismiss the dialog once got all details
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

Comment: This is the best and clearest most helpful answer. It solved the problem right away, I see what I did wrong now, I returned the product outside the try and catch block before, and keep getting error, stupid mistake, anyway thank you so much for your help. =)

Comment: I didn't do it here, but since you can return null from `doInBackground`, you need to do a null check in `onPostExecute` and handle it appropriately

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of error i can find in your code. The biggest one, and that you really need to fix, is that you don´t need a `runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {` on your `doInBackground()`, mostly becouse this method is intended to be run in the background, where you can do your requests. The result of the request must be passed to `onPostExecute()`, this method already runs in the ui thread. So you should update the ui there.

The methods findViewById must be called in the `onCreate()`. Try this and tell me what happens.

Comment: yup I know, the thing is after I remove the runOnUiThread, I don't know how to pass the request result to onPostExecute() and to update this, should I move the whole try block to onPostExecute() class ? I moved                             txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
                            txtPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
                            txtDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc); block to onCreate() but I still get RuntimeException

Comment: You method `doInBackground` should return your variable success.`onPostExecute` receives this variable as a parameter, then you should continue from there.

Comment: tried return success, it said "Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to String

Comment: That's becouse your `onPostExecute` is receiving a String. Change it, or pass the int as String in the return.

Comment: String strI = String.valueOf(success); I did this and return strI, still got the error of strI cannot be resolved into a variable

Answer (score 0):

@Charas,

I investigate your code and remove your problem. you call the "UI thread" in the background and call the network operation at the UI. So You face this type of the problem. Please use the following piece of code and Enjoy Coding....

```
    package com.example.test;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    public class EditProductActivity extends Activity {

        EditText txtName;
        EditText txtPrice;
        EditText txtDesc;
        EditText txtCreatedAt;
        Button btnSave;
        Button btnDelete;

        String pid;

        //progress Dialog
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        //JSON parser class
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

        //single product url
        private static final String url_product_details = "http://api.kerjaapa.com/android_connect/get_product_details.php";

        //url to update product
        private static final String url_update_product = "http://api.kerjaapa.com/android_connect/update_product.php";

        //url to delete product
        private static final String url_delete_product = "http://api.kerjaapa.com/android_connect/delete_product.php";

        //JSON Node names
        private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
        private static final String TAG_PRODUCT = "product";
        private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
        private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
        private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";
        private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.edit_product);

            //save button
            btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
            btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

            //getting product details from intent
            Intent i = getIntent();

            //getting product id(pid) from intent
            pid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_PID);

            //getting complete product details in background thread
            new GetProductDetails().execute();

            //save button click event
            btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    //starting background task to update product
                    new SaveProductDetails().execute();
                }
            });

            //Delete button click event
            btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    //deleting product in background thread
                    new DeleteProduct().execute();
                }
            });
        }

        //Background Async Task to Get Complete Product Details
        class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
            //Before starting background thread show progress dialog
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Loading product details. Please wait...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            //getting product details in background thread
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                        //Check for success tag
                        int success;
                        try {
                            //Building Parameters
                            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                            //getting product details by making HTTP request
                            //Note that product details url will use GET request
                            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                                    url_product_details, "GET", params);

                            //check your log for json response
                            Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                            //json success tag
                            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            }


                return null;
            }

            //After completing background task dismiss the progress dialog
            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                //dismiss the dialog once got all details
                pDialog.dismiss();

 if (success == 1) {
                                //successfully received product details
                                JSONArray productObj = json
                                    .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); //JSON Array

                                //get first product object from JSON Array
                                JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                                //product with this pid found
                                //Edit text
                                txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
                                txtPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
                                txtDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

                                //display product data in editText
                                txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
                                txtPrice.setText(product.getString(TAG_PRICE));
                                txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));

                            } else {
                                //product with pid not found
                            }
            }

        }

        //Background Async Task to Save product details
        class SaveProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            //Before starting background thread, show dialog
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Saving product ...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            //Saving product
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

                //getting updated data from EditTexts
                String name = txtName.getText().toString();
                String price = txtPrice.getText().toString();
                String description = txtDesc.getText().toString();

                //Building parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PID, pid));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_NAME, name));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PRICE, price));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description));

                //sending modified data through http request
                //Notice that update product url accepts POST method
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_update_product, 
                    "POST", params);

                //check json success tag
                try {
                    int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }

            //After completing background task, dismiss dialog
            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                //dismiss dialog
                pDialog.dismiss();
 if (success == 1) {
                        //successfully updated
                        Intent i = getIntent();
                        //send result code 100 to notify about product update
                        setResult(100, i);
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        //failed to update product
                    }
            }    
        }

        //Background async task to delete product
        class DeleteProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            //Before starting, show progress dialog
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Deleting Product...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            //Deleting product
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {


                //check for success tag
                int success;
                try {
                    //Building parameters
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                    //getting product details by making HTTP request
                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                            url_delete_product, "POST", params);

                    //check your log for json response
                    Log.d("Delete product", json.toString());

                    //json success tag
                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }

            //After completing background task dismiss dialog
            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                //dismiss dialog once finish
                pDialog.dismiss();
if (success == 1) {
                        //product successfully deleted
                        //notify previous activity by sending code 100
                        Intent i = getIntent();
                        //send result code 100 to notify about product deletion
                        setResult(100, i);
                        finish();
                    }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, I tried this too before, and this is what I get :  success cannot be resolved to a variable on the onPostExecute(). also json cannot be resolved inside the onPostExecute() in the doInBackground()

Comment: please pass the json result in the onPostExecute(String result) and then get String result as a json and parse it.